# how to get the UID of NFC mobile in Android?

Tags: android

I want to get UID of NFC enabled mobile in android so dat my application can recognise this UID and match it with the UID in DataBase .

I have tried some api  dat read uid of NFC tags but need to read UID of Mobile phone ..

Thanks in Advance.!!!!

Comment: Hello, could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: I dont know what you have tried but you can reffer this link may it helps you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797030/how-to-detect-in-android-whether-uid-from-nfc-tag-is-random